# How do I successfully change the state in one component from another?

Tags: reactjs

I am calling setState in one component in an onClick function in another component but it says this.setState is not a function and that a component is repeatedly calling setState inside componentWill update. How do i fix this?
This is the relevant of the app.js file:
    export default class App extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        activeScreen: 'dashboard'
    }
}

setActiveScreen(key) {
    this.setState({
        activeScreen: key
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <NavBar activeScreen={this.state.activeScreen} setActiveScreen={this.setActiveScreen} />
    )
}
```

This is the relevant part of the Navbar component:

```
class NavBar extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <li className="nav-item" key={key}>
             <Link className={`nav-link ${this.props.activeScreen == i.key ? 'active' : ''}`} to={i.to} onClick={() => {this.props.setActiveScreen(i.key)}}>
                 {i.label}
             </Link>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: you should bind setActiveScreen or use arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the `setActiveScreen` function to `this` in the constructor of your App component.

Like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        activeScreen: 'dashboard'
    }
    this.setActiveScreen = this.setActiveScreen.bind(this);
}
```

Or, as @Nico said in the comments, use an arrow function.

Like this:

```
setActiveScreen = key => {
  // logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this function in a Class based component then you can update your current function to an arrow function like below.

```
    setActiveScreen = (key) => {
     this.setState({
        activeScreen: key
     })
    }
```

The thing is you are accessing this without a context being given.

Another way can be you bind this to the function. Below is the example to do it the other way inside your constructor.

```
  constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.setActiveScreen = this.setActiveScreen.bind(this);
 // Other code ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First every methods how use setState has to be bind in the constructor like this :

`this.setActiveScreen = this.setActiveScreen.bind(this);`

Secondly, just for the good practice define your props in `NavBar` like this :

```
static propTypes = {
        setActiveScreen: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }
```

Thirdly, is not a good practice to use arrow function in your render. So you have to possibility :

Using `partial` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partial)
so it looks like this :

`<Link onClick={ _.partial(this.props.setActiveScreen, i.key)}}>`

Or you can define a specific method in your NavBar component called by onClick and you retrieve your key in the event object provide by default by onClick